# Saving to session in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When a user encounters a specific type of error, on Global.asax we update the session variable IsErrorEncountered, save the session and redirect the users back to the Dashboard page. On the Dashboard page, when I try to access this session variable it does not reflect the changes I've made in Global.asax. Why is the session not being saved? Can someone please tell me if I can even update my session from Global.asax?

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   Dim session As SessionData = HttpContext.Current.Session("SessionData")
   sessionData.IsErrorEncountered = True
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("SessionData", session)

   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard/Index")

End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is ... please edit.

Comment: *This code is in Global.asax.*. Nope. It's not.

Comment: Sorry I guess I hit the enter too fast

Comment: Where does the variable `sessionData` come from? Try changing `sessionData.IsErrorEncountered = True` to `session.IsErrorEncountered = True`.  I'm assuming that IsErrorEncountered is a property in the `SessionData` class which is the instantiated `session` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your session token cookie is being lost when redirecting. Try to use the overloaded version of Response.Redirect method:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   Dim session As SessionData = HttpContext.Current.Session("SessionData")
   sessionData.IsErrorEncountered = True
   HttpContext.Current.Session("SessionData") = session

   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard/Index", false)
   HttpContext.Server.ClearError();
End Sub
```

Comment: Session.Add() also updates the session if it finds the key "SessionData". I did try your solution and it did not work.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution that should work for you

Comment: Does your problem occur with HTTP 500 (Server Error), with 404 (File Not Found) or with all kind of errors? Btw maybe you could try executing HttpContext.Server.ClearError() at the end of your method?